# Chooser is not working

Tags: android

in my app i want to display the location using map and also browsers(i need to display what are all the browser that installed in the device.) using the Chooser.please any one help me to find a solution.Thanks in advance. and also i need to set that always just once button in it.....

[image]

```
                    String format = "geo:0,0?q=" + Double.toString(latter)
                            + "," + Double.toString(longer) + "(" + sender
                            + ")";
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(format);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"));
```

Comment: did you override the OnActivityResult() method?

Comment: Web browsers will not respond to `geo:` `Intent` structures, normally.

Comment: How would a browser display location? Do you mean that the browser should load a map provided by Google Maps or Bing or MapQuest or some other web-based map provider? That will not happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

// Always use string resources for UI text. This says something like "Share this photo with"
String title = getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title);
// Create and start the chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link as an example to implement chooser in android https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser